# How can I split a string, remove an element, then re-join?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I want to split a string at every `-`, remove the `n`th element from the split string for a given `n`, and then rejoin the string with `-`.

The string I have is:

```rb
s = '2.3-6020-1010.1-4.0-M-671924'
```

The modified string I require is:

```rb
'2.3-6020-4.0-M-671924'
```

I tried with the `split` and `delete_at` methods, but it didn't work:

```rb
s.split('-').delete_at(2).join('-')
```

The error is:

> NoMethodError: undefined method 'join' for "1010.1".

Comment: Please elaborate on *how* you tried and *how* it didn't work.

Comment: I'd go with split/join, yes. Or, possibly, regexes. Depending on the structure (what strings are possible)

Comment: What are the rules for getting the result?

Comment: Without any rules, `s.sub('1010.1-', '')` :D

Comment: See docs for [delete_at](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_at). "Deletes the element at the specified index, returning that element, or nil if the index is out of range." Whatever it returns, nil or element, it's not a good idea to call `join` on that. Don't chain the call to join, call it on the next line. In broad strokes, `ary = str.split; ary.delete_at; str = ary.join`

Comment: There are no specific rules for getting the result. I just wanted to modify the string to save it.

Comment: @current_user How are you supposed to code it, if there are "no specific rules"?? That doesn't make any sense. You might as well just write `s = '2.3-6020-4.0-M-671924'` and call it a day, then.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the comment. The rule is to split the string with "-" and remove the nth element from the split string.

Comment: This question is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411161).

Comment: @MichaelB that comment can now go as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem in a nutshell just seems to be that you missed the fact that `delete_at` returns the deleted element and not the modified array. There are a few methods you can use, some of which have been mentioned, but here's one that's as close as I can think of to what you tried:

```
s.split('-').values_at(0..1, 3..-1).join("-")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also split by more than 1 character, so this should work:

```
s = s.split('1010.1-').join
```

It would split, create an array and then join.

Comment: Please note that the question has been edited to be more general, so your answer won't work now. You might want to edit your answer accordingly.